# Node js Fetch send empty body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, request

I'm creating a rest api, I did everything right on the server, when I try to use fetch, always say "count" is not set, I try to give console.log (req.body) on the server and I always get {}

```js
app.post("/api/stats/:id", async (req, res) => {
  let botId = req.params.id;

  console.log(req.body);

  let auth = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!auth)
    return res.json({
      success: "false",
      error: "Authorization header not found."
    });    

  let count = req.body.count ? req.body.count : req.body.server_count;

  if (!count) return res.json({ success: "false", error: "Count not found in body." });

  count = parseInt(count);

  if (!count) return res.json({ success: "false", error: "Count not integer." });

  const bot = client.fetchUser(`${botId}`);

  if (!bot) return res.json({ success: "false", error: "Bot not found." });

  // if (!bot.auth) return res.json({ "success": "false", "error": "Create a bot authorization  token." });

  //if (bot.auth !== auth) return res.json({ "success": "false", "error": "Incorrect  authorization token." });
  bot.servers = count;

  res.json({ success: "true", bot: bot });
});
```

Client side -Node js code:

```js
const body = { count: 1 };

fetch("https://www.cloudlist.xyz/api/stats/64492636015388263", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `MY AUTH`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ body })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(async response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

The errors that I get:

client side

[image: client side]

server side

[image: server side]

Comment: Have you got `app.use(express.json())` or similar [request body-parsing](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) configured?

Comment: Ah, never mind. Try `body: JSON.stringify(body)`. Using `JSON.stringify({ body })` would result in `{"body":{"count":1}}` which means you'd have to use `req.body.body.count`

Comment: Same Thing @Phil

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. You haven't answered my first question and if you've changed your code based on my second comment, please update the code in your question to match

Comment: I am using app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); I tried to add just body,but I am getting the same error @Phil

Comment: If you're posting JSON in your requests, you should be using `app.use(express.json())` (if using Express v4) or `app.use(bodyParser.json())` otherwise

Comment: Thanks,Did not know that,working now @Phil